# How to access the label control of list view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access one of the labels inside the `DataList` control. How can I access that in my code behind file (C#)?  I'm using Visual Studio 2010

I want to access text property of "productnamelabel"

My code is:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            productName:
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Label ID="productNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>' />
            <br />
            brand:
            <asp:Label ID="brandLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("brand") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' />
            <br />
            catagory:
            <asp:Label ID="catagoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("catagory") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>' />
            <br />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:shopingConnectionString1 %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [productName], [brand], [image], [catagory], [price] FROM [product] WHERE ([productName] = @productName)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="productName" QueryStringField="pName" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `FindControl` method.  Like so:

```
Label lbl = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("productNameLabel");
lbl.text = "stuff";
```

**EDIT:** To get to ***every*** `Label` in your `DataList`, you need to iterate through all of the `DataListItem`s that have been generated by the `DataList`.  Then you can go through each `Control` collection and access the `Labels`.

```
foreach (DataListItem i in DataList1.Items) // Iterates through each of your Items
{
    foreach (Control c in i.Controls) // Iterates through all the Controls in each Item
    {
        if (c is Label) // Make sure the control is a Label control
        {
            Label temp = (Label)c;
            temp.Text = "junk";
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I don't know if this is the best way to do this, it's just what came to mind.

Comment: actually my problem is not solved yet.my datalist create many labels and i want to access text value of labels but don't know how

Comment: @prakash: I've updated my answer.  I'm not entirely sure I understand what your asking, but I hope that helps.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Casting a control to `Label` and catching the exception, is like throwing kids in the pool to see if they can swim. You could just ask the control if it is a label (`if (c is Label){...}`.

Comment: @SWeko: I did not know that, very cool!  I'll update the answer =).  Also...LOL at the analogy.

Answer (score 1):

```
The code below shows the contents of an aspx file, which contains two label controls, and two SqlDataSource controls. Each SqlDataSource control has its DataSource mode set to alternative values - DataSet and DataReader, and both of them have an OnSelecting event defined in which the value of the EmployeeID parameter is assigned:

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />

<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    DatasourceMode="DataSet"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [LastName], [FirstName] FROM [Employees] WHERE ([EmployeeID] = ?)" 
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="SqlDataSource2" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    DatasourceMode="DataReader"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [LastName], [FirstName] FROM [Employees] WHERE ([EmployeeID] = ?)" 
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

The following code snippet shows the aspx.cs file contents, where the parameter values are set in the Selecting event handler. In the Page_Load method, the data returned by each of the Sql DataSource controls is accessed and a value consigned to a label. The method of access depends on the DataSource mode, but is identical for both SqlDataSource and AccessDataSource:

[C#]
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataView dvSql = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRowView drvSql in dvSql)
    {
        Label1.Text = drvSql["FirstName"].ToString();
    }

    OleDbDataReader rdrSql = (OleDbDataReader)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    while (rdrSql.Read())
    {
        Label2.Text = rdrSql["LastName"].ToString();

    }
    rdrSql.Close();
}



protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["EmployeeID"].Value = 2;
}

protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["EmployeeID"].Value = 2;
}
```